# Should "freopen'ed" stdout be closed?

Tags: c, file-descriptor, fclose, freopen

In a C or C++ program I can use [freopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/) to redirect the output (i.e. the stdout file descriptor) to another file (or to discard it be reopening the file descriptor to /dev/null or another sink).

The question is: if I do so, should I take care of closing the file descriptor explicitly before the program ends the execution? Why? On which platforms? What happens in general and in this specific case if I don't close a file descriptor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Should I take care of closing the file descriptor explicitly before the program ends the execution?**

   From the [`freopen(3)` man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/freopen/):

   > The **`freopen()`** function opens the file whose name is the string pointed to
   >    by *filename* and associates the stream pointed to by stream with it.  The
   >    original stream (if it exists) is closed.

   So no, you don't have to close the original `FILE *`.  You should probably close the one you get back from the `freopen` call, though.  BTW - these are all `FILE *` variables, not file descriptors.
2. **Why?**

   Because the documentation says you don't have to.
3. **On which platforms?**

   Any that correctly implement `freopen(3)` as defined by the C standard.
4. **What happens in general and in this specific case if I don't close a file descriptor?**

   The operating system cleans up the resources used by your program when your program exits.

Comment: Why should the file pointer return get back from the freopen() be closed?